# Order the collection in a fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A `Controller` has many `Post`.

In the view I'm iterating a controllers associated posts with the following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :posts do |builder|  %>
  <%= render 'post_fields', builder: builder %>
<% end %>
```

How can I control by which attribute the `posts` are ordered and displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller's corresponding action to this view,

Set an instance variable ordered as per your requirement. For example:

```
def action_name
  ## ....
  @posts = @model_instance.posts.order(attrb: :desc)  
end
```

Where replace

- `@model_instance` with the associated instance of model.
- `attrb` with which you would like to order
- `desc` for descending order or `asc` for ascending order

After this in your view, update your `fields_for` as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for @posts, :posts do |builder|  %>
  <%= render 'post_fields', builder: builder %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think the `@posts` and `:posts` need to be reversed from your example.

https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for